# WPF: How do I get different templates based on a list-item's type?

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

I heard that I could create a collection of mixed types and have a different Data Template for each type. How woudl I do that for a ListBox?

Answer (score -1):

`ItemTemplateSelector` property of `ListBox` is made specifically for that.

Answer (score -1):

And you need a class inheriting from DataTemplateSelector and then override the SelectTemplate method:

```
public class SomeTemplateSelector:DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(((YourDataContextClass)item).SomeLogic)
            return FirstTemplate;
        else
            return OtherTemplate;
    }
 }
```